# Save text file to rimatted docx from bash

Tags: linux, bash, formatting, libreoffice

I am very desperate. I have data which I need to preprocess in terminal bash. Then I need to save my data in document with special formatting - like font, letter size etc = create REPORT to be readable in Libreoffice or Word.

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

BOLD='\033[1m'

format2="%10s"

printf "\n \n"

echo -e "${BOLD}THIS I WANT TO KEEP BOLD IN DOCUMENT:${NONE}"
awk 'BEGIN{print "COL1","COL2","COL3","COL4","COL5"}'  | column -t | sed 2i$(printf "=%.0s" {1..50}) 


printf "=%.0s" {1..50}

printf "\n \n"


#printf "=%.0s" {1..45}
#printf "\n"
printf "$format2" "DESCRIBE CLASS:"
printf "\n \n"
printf "$format2" "1. CLASS"
printf "\n"
printf "$format2" "2. CLASS"
printf "\n"
printf "$format2" "3. CLASS"
printf "\n"
printf "$format2" "4. CLASS" 
printf "\n \n"
```

When I run `./script.sh > foo.doc`

When I open my document in Libre `xdg-open foo.doc` I do not have text in bold. I also need to have specific font (verdana) and font size.

I really do not know how to format text in bash to direct open in Libre/Word..

It is possible?

Comment: `\033[1m` is a bash meta-character. For example, if you `echo -e "\033[1mtest"`, you'll see test written in bold (you should also close the bold part, which is probably what you tried to do with the undefined `${NONE}`, but it doesn't matter here). For Libre Word, it probably means nothing, and what you've got is a simple text file with some weird characters here and there, in contrast with the binary (well, zipped xml actually) files that these kind of editor read and produce.

Comment: There must be some tools to produce word documents from text files out there, or another option would be to look into RTF (Rich Text Format), which is probably the closest to what you're currently doing : text files, with a few styling hints which combine the simplicity of text files with a better formatting.

Comment: Another option could be to use the text file you've produced in an application that would both be able to understand those meta-characters and produce a file readable with word. I'm thinking emacs could maybe do the trick, especially if you don't mind pdf files as the ouput format

Comment: Thank you aaron for comment. I know, that what I have is just text file with weird characters. I just wanted to show example and what I want. Best output for me is document. I found some solution in Latex, but output is only pdf. Google did not help me.. Just trying this way...

Comment: Looks like [this](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/index.html) could help. They've got a text format named reStructuredText and an utility to convert it to .odt files which you'll be able to read and edit using one of the *office suites

Comment: Also see [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1033441), where a guy could convert latex files to .odt and .doc

Comment: Or maybe [this python library](http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/) which can produce or edit .odt files.

Comment: I have no experience with either of them so I couldn't tell which is best

Comment: Dear Aaaron, I am very appreciate your research - some links looks very useful!!! I will check it and if I found solution I let you know. I still have a problem to "Ask" google. I Believe that some solution have to somewhere. Best!

Comment: You're welcome Paul, good luck with your task !